# Ruby's case equality operator (`===`) is backwards for RSpec's `expect`

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm running a bunch of data-driven specs, and the expected data is in different classes (because I have to use Regexps sometimes, because the output string changes each time but always follows a specific format).

An expression that works perfectly to check them all is Ruby's case equality operator, `===`. The problem is that it works backwards compared to most Ruby expressions, and sometimes the operation is asymmetrical:

```
/rgx a/ === b # equivalent to b =~ /rgx a/
ClassA  === b # equivalent to b.is_a? ClassA
```

In the context of my specs, this means I have to put the operands the wrong way round:

```
[Class, /regex/, 'string'].each do |expected_data|
  it { expect(expected_data).to be === actual_data }
end
```

And this leads to incorrect failure messages:

```
expected: === "Actual data"
     got:     "Expected data"
```

Is there a way to reverse **either** the `===` operator **or** the `expect` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out RSpec has a very flexible [satisfy matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/satisfy-matcher). I can change the `expect` syntax as follows and it does exactly what I need:

```
expect(actual_data).to satisfy { |v| expected_data === v }
```

*(Edited - thanks [@Glyoko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4067720/glyoko))* The default failure message is a little more obtuse (`expected [actual data] to satisfy block`), but you can also pass a description to `#satisfy`:

```
expect(actual_data).to satisfy("match #{expected_data}") { |v| expected_data === v }
```

The default description for the spec (i.e. if you pass no description to `#it`) is then `[context/description] should match [expected data]`, and the failure message is `expected [actual data] to match [expected data]`.

Comment: You can also pass an argument to satisfy that be the error message if the spec fails. e.g. `satisfy("=== #{expected_data}") { # test }`. The error message in this case would be "expected #{actual_data} to === #{expected_data}"

Answer (score 1):

If it comes down to it, you could define your own matcher for this:

```
describe 'reverse case eq' do
  it { expect('regex').to reverse_case_eq /regex/ }
  it { expect('bad match').to reverse_case_eq /regex/ } # fails
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :reverse_case_eq do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected === actual
  end
end
```

The error message in this case looks like:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: it { expect('bad match').to reverse_case_eq /regex/ }
>    expected "bad match" to reverse case eq /regex/
> ```

You can also add

```
  failure_message do |actual|
    "expected #{expected.inspect} to === #{actual.inspect}"
  end
```

to the define block, and then the fail message would become

> ```
> Failure/Error: it { expect('bad match').to reverse_case_eq /regex/ }
>    expected /regex/ to === "bad match"
> ```

This might be preferred if you find yourself frequently running into this use case.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular use case, you can use RSpec's [`match` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher), which tries first `expected === actual`, and if that fails, `actual.match(expected)`:

```rb
expect('xyz').to match('xyz')
# 'xyz' === 'xyz'     => true => comparison successful

expect('xyz').not_to match('xyzw')
# 'xyzw' === 'xyz'    => false
# 'xyz'.match('xyzw') => nil  => comparison failed

expect('xyz').to match('y')
# 'y' === 'xyz'       => false
# 'xyz'.match('y')    => #<MatchData "y"> => comparison successful

expect('xyz').not_to match(/^y$/)
# /^y$/ === 'xyz'     => false
# 'xyz'.match(/^y$/)  => nil  => comparison failed

expect('xyz').to match(/y/)
# /y/ === 'xyz'       => true => comparison successful

expect({}).to match(Hash)
# Hash === {}         => true => comparison successful
```

Comment: Oh this looks simple, does it also fix the failure messages?

Comment: @PJSCopeland It does, e.g. `expect('xyz').to match('xyzw')` gets you `expected "xyz" to match "xyzw"` -- quite straightforward.